why the eigen values of a random matrix are not the same?
I'm lacking the intuition for the eigen values distribution of a random matrix following Marchenko–Pastur distribution. If a random matrix is formed with i.i.d samples drawn from standard normal distribution, then there shouldn't be any cross-correlation by definition(covariance matrix equal to the identity). In geometric sense, It should give me an ideal higher dimensional spherical distribution with same variance in all directions. Therefore, I expect same variance and similar eigen values irrespective of eigen vector direction. Where is the flaw in my train of thoughts?
Similar question:

Intuitive explanation for Marchenko-Pastur law

In the answer to this question, Author claims there could be some "true correlation structure" leading to higher eigen values. But, I don't understand the origin of these cross-correlation. Is it intrinsic to multi-variate normal distribution? or it arises from non-ideal sample size, numerical precision, random number generator?
Thanks a lot!

The flaw is that you're ignoring variability due to random sampling.
Think about the case of a 2-d random matrix, where each dimension is an independant Normal distribution with a mean of $0$ and standard deviation of $1$.
$$
X \sim N(
 \begin{bmatrix} 
0&0
 \end{bmatrix}
,
 \begin{bmatrix} 
1&0\\
0&1
 \end{bmatrix}
)
$$
If you sample from this distribution, you won't end up two variables with means of exactly $0$ and a covariance/correlation of exactly $0$. Instead, the observed correlation will follow the distribution described here.
The Marchenko–Pastur distribution generalises this idea to the eigenvalues of the observed covariance matrix for higher-dimensional cases.
To put this in other words, if you sample from a distribution with a identity covariance matrix, your observed sample won't have exactly an identity covariance matrix.
